# Detect YouTube Red video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to detect if a video is a Youtube Red video using the Youtube Data Api? The "kind" property on these videos are "youtube#video" just like all other videos and I can't find any way to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but you could listen to the state changes via `onStateChange` event. When a Youtube Red video loads, it goes from 3 (Buffering) to -1 (Unstarted). That was a good enough indication for me.

```
if (prevState === 3 && nextState === -1) {
  // Handle YT Red video (in my case, skip)
}
```